# How to pass only zipcode in array

Tags: php

We saved address as below image in Database :

[image]

Here **803110 is zip code of customer**, i tried to fetch this zip code and pass it in array as below :

```
$sqlh="SELECT order_id, address  FROM do_order where order_id='".$order_id."'";
$resulth = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqlh);

$address=explode(",",$resulth['address']);
$countadd=count($address);
$pincode=$address[$countadd-1];

$data = 
array (
'OrderNo' => $order_id,
'ZipCode' => $pincode,
);
```

I got `Notice: Undefined index: address` & i tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined) before posting question, but that not worked for me....

[here is full code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/AvFYNx99)

Comment: Are you sure the zip code will always be at last?

Comment: @VidhyutPandya Thanks for reply , yes.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: @billynoah Thanks , i already tried that link, but it did't helped me.....

Comment: `$resulth` almost certainly contains an array or object of rows.  You are accessing it as if it was a single row.  dump the output, get your answer

Comment: @billynoah sorry, please post your comment as answer...... `$address = explode(",",$resulth[0]['address']);`

Comment: it's ok - looks like you've figured it out.  normally any query is going to return an array of results but it really depends how `runSelectQuery()` is written and I was only making an educated guess.

Comment: @billynoah `so need experience guys like you always` , thanks again......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the last element of an array using the `end()` function.

Try this

```
$address = explode(",",$resulth['address']); 
//or can try explode(",",$resulth[0]['address']) if $resulth is multidimensional array
$pincode = end($address);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/1061959)

Comment: provide the output of `$resulth`

Comment: sorry, this worked for me : `$address = explode(",",$resulth[0]['address']);`